# How to ignore a spurious ReactServerComponentsError error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I have a Next.js project using the App router.

One of my API routes wants to import a function "X" from a library that also happens to import another library that imports `useEffect`. Function X itself doesn't rely on `useEffect`, or any of React.

Because I'm in an API route on the server-side, I get a runtime `ReactServerComponentsError`

I'm not relying on that `useEffect` in any way, so how can I tell Next/React to ignore that error?

The error message:

```
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
```

Comment: Please provide more details including which library you are trying to use, etc. so that others can help.